# Write command doesn't print everything on the same line

Tags: python, file

I am using the following commands inside a Loop to open a .txt file and write some results on the file.

```
with open ('results.txt', 'a') as file: 
    file.write('%s %d %s %s \n' %(timestamp, v, str(dcur), str(gcur)))
```

However, the results are not printed on the same line at the .txt file and str(gcur) appears on the next one.

Why does this happen and how could it be solved?

Comment: try with `(timestamp, v, str(dcur).rstrip("\n"), str(gcur).rstrip("\n")))`

Comment: @AthinaPap It is because of \n in your file.write

Comment: If you have no `\n` in your strings `gcur and dcur`, then it should not happen. Could you give a complete example with inputs and outputs? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably is because when calling `str` to `dcur` it adds a `"\n"` somehow.

You can **stript** it:

```
with open ('results.txt', 'a') as file: 
    file.write('%s %d %s %s \n'.format(timestamp, v, str(dcur).rstript("\n"), str(gcur).rstript("\n")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the format string `'%s %d %s %s \n'` in which `%s` and `%d` are replaced by `timestamp, v, str(dcur), str(gcur)` variables.  Note the `\n` in the end of your format string — this is newline character.  You should remove it if you want everything to be printed on the same line, like this:

```
with open ('results.txt', 'a') as file: 
    file.write('%s %d %s %s' %(timestamp, v, str(dcur), str(gcur)))
```